# Install full version of manpages on macOS

Tags: macos, command-line, bsd, manpage

some tools such as nm have no manpages on macOS

for example:

`$ man nm
No manual entry for nm`

but online manpage is available from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html

according to this page:
https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/#

> indicate manual pages that are not installed by default in the client version of Mac OS X

But how to get these additional manpage installed?

Comment: I guess you could make your own by running something like `nm —help` and directing the output to the appropriate place in `/usr/share/man/somewhere` or wherever...

Comment: -help and manpage don't provide the same information and I think manpages are needed anyway.

Comment: For `nm` and other GNU utilities, try `info nm` to get the manual page or something similar. `info` is an old GNU program for reading documentation. I don't know where to get real manual pages for the `man` program, unfortunately.